# Why do I need a global variable to break out of an .after() loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global

I am trying to make a simple stopwatch in tkinter python, and so far it works fine if the "pause" variable is set as a global variable. However, I'm having a hard time understanding why I need to keep my "pause" variable as a global since I am working with a class. When I try to make the "pause" variable into a class attribute (self.pause), the pausing mechanism stops working. I'm new to tkinter and haven't needed to use global variables at all before this so I'm purely just trying to understand what's going on. Any explanations are much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

#add zeroes ahead of integers < 10
def isec(i):
    s = f"{i/10:e}"
    try:
        zeroes = int(s[s.index("-")+1:])
        idnum=f"{str(0)*zeroes}{i}"
    #nothing is done to the number if it is > 10
    except ValueError:
        idnum = str(i)
    return idnum

class SW:
    def __init__(self):
        self.second = 0
        self.minute = 0
        self.hour = 0
        global pause
        pause = 0

        self.label = Label(root, text="")
        self.label.pack()

    def stopwatch(self):
        if pause == 1:
            print(self.hour, self.minute, self.second)
            return self.hour, self.minute, self.second
        self.label.after(1000, self.stopwatch)

        self.second+=1
        if self.second > 59:
            self.second = 0
            self.minute+=1

        if self.minute > 59:
            self.minute = 0
            self.hour+=1

        self.label.config(text = f"{isec(self.hour)}:{isec(self.minute)}:{isec(self.second)}")

    def start(self):
        global pause
        pause = 0
        self.stopwatch()    

    def pause(self):
        global pause
        pause = 1

sw = SW()       

Starttimer = Button(root, text="Start", command=sw.start)
Starttimer.pack()
Pausetimer = Button(root, text="Pause", command = sw.pause)
Pausetimer.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show the code that fails with the instance variable, not the code that works.

Comment: General style: Use `True/False` rather than `1/0` for flags.

Comment: there is no reason you shouldnt be able to use self.pause instead

Comment: The problem is that your `pause` instance variable has the same name as the `pause()` method. So when you assign `self.pause = 0`, you no longer have a `self.pause()` method that pauses the stopwatch.

Comment: Give the instance variable a different name.

Comment: @Barmar changing the name of the instance variable fixed it, thank you!